# Federal courts under the Articles of Confederation

Tags: federal-courts, history

This is meeting with silence at history.stackexchange.com, so I'm trying it here:

The ninth Article of Confederation establishes federal judicial jurisdiction in some cases, including "disputes and differences now subsisting or that hereafter may arise between two or more States concerning boundary, jurisdiction or any other causes whatever" and "controversies concerning the private right of soil claimed under different grants of two or more States" and some others. It provides that whenever a case is filed with the Continental Congress, a temporary federal court will be appointed to hear the case.

Is there any published account of the history of federal courts under the Articles of Confederation?